# Hiding List Item in Hamburger Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to hide a list item that is inside a jQuery "hamburger" menu. Before I added the menu, a simple `display: none` hid the item from the other media queries. But when I added the hamburger menu it reappeared.

There's a separate .css file for the menu, so perhaps it must be put in that as well, but nothing works. Here the HTML. It's the bottom li I'm trying to hide.

```
<nav class="style-nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('soc_Instagram','','Images/soc_Instagram_rollover.png',1)"><img id="soc_Instagram" src="Images/soc_Instagram.png" alt="This links to my Instagram page"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The list item id is `soc_Instagram` and appears in the *css* as

```
#soc_Instagram {
    display: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

The css you have for #soc_Instagram is only being applied to the image. You can try adding a css rule for the last list item.

Something as simple as adding a class to it

```
                <nav class="style-nav">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li class='Hidden'><a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('soc_Instagram','','Images/soc_Instagram_rollover.png',1)"><img id="soc_Instagram" src="Images/soc_Instagram.png" alt="This links to my Instagram page"></a>Hide this one</li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
```

And then the css would just be applied to the new class

```
.Hidden {
    display: none;
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. I even tried putting it in slicknav.css (the hamburger menu css file), but all that did was make it disappear in the places I want it to be seen, but not in the hamburger menu.

Does it have to be indented under another class, such as the .slicknav class?